# Rails Paperclip: Do not store uploaded file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I have a use case in which the user uploads a CSV file and I am only interested on the values extracted but still I am using paperclip for the conveniences of the model orientation.

Is there a way to tell paperclip to not store the attachment?

I have tried using:

```
def before_save
 self.csv_attachment = nil
end
```

But still the files gets stored.

Comment: You don't want to save a CSV file after reading it? is that what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Correct I take the values to memory only. Well not exactly I also used them to fill a PDF form but yes after I get them I dont care about the CSV anymore

Comment: But, you can not read a file without saving it on server? If, you don't want that file after processing then delete it. `def after_save   #process that file then self.destroy end`

Answer (score 0):

Before saving the model, nil out the attribute.

```
def create
  @user = User.new( params[:user] )
  @user.image = nil
  @user.save
end
```

Comment: I was thinking something like this, but will paperclip still create directories etc. during preprocessing?

Comment: I assume that would work, but in the model I was validating the presence of the attachment for the form to require the CSV file and complain about its absence, so if I set to nil before saving it still complain about its absence.